# Sum filter by date with many different record and different rows

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

I have a few record of company. Below is the sample of it but sometime the record might hit 400 company.

I want to sum up the amount before 2013. meaning that sum up everything include 2012, but I want each individual company have sum of its own.

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"<=2013",B:B)
```

Assuming Column A contains the year only (do this by using a helper column to seperate the year eg. =text(C1,"YYYY") copy that all the way down (assuming date is in column C) then format the cells as number

Column B contains the data you want to sum

Criteria <=2013 will sum all values less than 2013

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Apologies...for each company to have its own SUM use the following

```
 =SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,"<=2013",C:C,E1)
```

B - values you want to sum 
A - year only (as per first answer) 
C - Company name column 
E1 (in this case) references the company name eg:

E1 - Company 1 
E2 - sumOfCompany1 goes here

Hope this is more what you're looking for.